# Is controller in mvc bound to object represented in application?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

Please enlighten me: If I'm implementing a simple application using MVC pattern, should controllers always be bound to objects existing in the application?

For example, if I'm implementing a Holiday Reservation Application and I specify such classes like: User, HolidayRequest, Holiday, etc, should the controllers be: UserController, HolidayRequestController and HolidayController?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller receives the input of your application and controls what happens with this input (i.e. which data is passed to the model, which actions the model should execute on it, and perhaps if the view needs to update itself).

The inputs I can see in your example are a *HolidayRequest*, and a *HolidayReservation*. Those would be separate actions on your controller, so I would create a *HolidayController* that implements those actions.

In general, I would recommend going for a *keep it simple* approach, if your application is not too complex, your architecture should be simple, too. Don't go implementing N controllers when all you need is one single class ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It makes sense.